# Perl script segfaulting after 64-bit upgrade

Tags: linux, 64-bit, perl, segmentation-fault

I recently upgraded a 32-bit Debian server to 64-bit by re-installing, and copying my data into place.

After this I have a perl script that repeats the following, and is segfaulting on the **tell** line:

```
seek(FIN,$ps,0);
tell(FIN, $ps);
$line=<FIN>;
```

I don't speak *perl*, so I'm not sure exactly what is going on here.  I can get the script to run (apparently successfully) by commenting every occurrence of tell, but this is obviously not the best solution.

I suspect that *tell* is calling a 32-bit binary or something, and that is the cause of the segfault - but I don't know.

Can someone **explain what tell does**, and if it is indeed a separate binary, **what package it belongs to** (or how it is installed ie. cpan)?

Or perhaps I am on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Perl docs at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html, `tell` has only one parameter and returns the current position.  Your code has two parameters.  Try this instead:

```
$ps = tell(FIN);
```

There should also be some error checking in case `tell` returns -1, which indicates an error.

Comment: but he's just seek'd to $ps.. so that seems a waste of time?

Think we need more context. What's the script? What is it supposed to do? Are you able to post it someplace?

Answer (score 0):

It is a [built-in function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html), but a segfault is a pretty harsh way for a perl script to die (this has *never* happened to me), so I have no clue what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, tell returns the current position of a filehandle.